# Unable to load Ubuntu iso from usb on my embedded board(no display)

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to load ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso iso image from usb onto my board.
I copied the iso image onto usb and booted my device, with boot from usb option.
Once booted it got struck-ed at below msg Note:

> My board is not having any display.

Error Msg:

```
Initializing gfx code...
graphics initialization failed 
Error setting up gfxboot
boot: help
Welcome to Ubuntu!                                               F1

This is an installation system for Ubuntu 14.04.
It was built on 20140722.3.

HELP INDEX

KEY    TOPIC

<F1>   This page, the help index.
<F2>   Prerequisites for installing Ubuntu.
<F3>   Boot methods for special ways of using this system.
<F4>   Additional boot methods; rescue mode.
<F5>   Special boot parameters, overview.
<F6>   Special boot parameters for special machines.
<F7>   Special boot parameters for selected disk controllers.
<F8>   Special boot parameters for the install system.
<F9>   How to get help.
<F10>  Copyrights and warranties.



Press F2 through F10 for details, or ENTER to boot:install
Undefined video mode number: 314
Press <ENTER> to see video modes available, <SPACE> to continue, or wait 30 sec
```

Device got struck-ed at above MSG.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the ENTER key to boot?  Did you try any of the function keys for options?

Comment: Hi ubfan, i tried enter but got strucked after enter. I tried install vga=noramal fb=false , expert vga=normal fb=false

Comment: Did you try  typing "Help" at the boot prompt?  See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594003

Comment: ya i gave help after that i came until Press <ENTER> to see video modes available, <SPACE> to continue, or wait 30 sec. Here it is asking for video scan modes. I doubt something is going wrong here. Since my board is not having display on it

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If so, please post what you had to do. I am stuck at the same stage!